# How to use CONTAINS filter on geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I draw a polygon on my map and I need to know if there are some features in it via WFS to get back a JSON. I guess I need to use CONTAINS property but when I read it it says that a contains b.

So I tried to write

> https://myurl.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&format_options=id_policy:reference_no=false&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=biglayer:layer&outputFormat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=CONTAINS(POLYGON((465995.8321513263%205177213.444093402,525922.4623269045%205157645.564852396,434809.5246109744%205123401.776180638,465995.8321513263%205177213.444093402)),geom)

But I've got the error

> Binary geometry filter, but first expression is not a property name?

If I put geom in first position, it returns me 0 feature, and I don't get it neither...

EDIT : Well I finally understood that I have to use WITHIN but I've still got no result... Here's my url :

> https://myurl.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&format_options=id_policy:reference_no=false&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=biglayer:layer&outputFormat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(geom,POLYGON((465995.8321513263%205177213.444093402,525922.4623269045%205157645.564852396,434809.5246109744%205123401.776180638,465995.8321513263%205177213.444093402)))

Any clue?

Comment: Are you expressing coordinages in the layer native CRS? That's a requirement for CQL filters.

Comment: also are you sure your geometry column is called 'geom'?

Comment: @AndreaAime Yep that was a CRS issue. I've been mistaken because of the srs condition with the bbox filter I used before. Thanks :)

Comment: @iant yep it solved, was a native CRS issue. Thank you !